# Sorting dataframe on column and checking difference of top two values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a dataframe `df`as:

```
  Election Year     Votes   Vote %      Party              Region   
0   2000            42289   29.40   Janata Dal (United)     A
1   2000            27618   11.20   Rashtriya Janata Dal    A
2   2000            20886   14.50   Bahujan Samaj Party     A 
3   2000            17747   12.40   Congress                B
4   2000            14047   9.50    Independent             B
5   2000            17047   10.80   JLS                     B
6   2005            8358    15.80   Janvadi Party           A
7   2005            4428    13.10   Independent             A
8   2005            1647    1.20    Ind                     A
9   2005            1610    11.10   Independent             B
10  2005            1334    15.06   Nationalist             B
11  2005            1834    28.06   NJM                     B
12  2010            21114   20.80   Independent             A
13  2010            1042    10.5    Bharatiya Janta Dal     A
14  2010            835     0.60    Independent             A
15  2010            14305   15.50   Independent             B
16  2010            22211   17.70   Congress                B
17  2010            20011   14.70   INC                     B
```

How can I get the dataframe containing regions with top two parties having difference in "Vote %" is less than 10?

Desired output:

```
Election Year    Region    Vote %
  2000             A        29.40
  2000             A        14.50
  2005             B        28.06
  2005             B        15.06
  2010             A        20.80
  2010             A        10.5
```

I tried by doing the grouping by "Election Year", and "Region". And then sorting based on "Vote %". But I am unable to figure out how to get all the regions having vote % difference less than 10.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: I think what you want to do is groupby your matches then generate a column which is basically "difference from the max value". After that, subset to the rows which match your 10pc thing and then return.

Comment: @ ifly6, Do I need to sort the column "Vote %" to get the difference of the top two values?

Comment: In 2000 with region A, the difference between the two largest parties is larger than 10 per cent. Is its inclusion in your output intentional? Also, your original data has two row '16's. Is that intentional?

Comment: @ifly6, That is a blunder. Actually I have to look for the regions having Vote% between top two parties less than 10%. So, the output should be different from what I have posted. Last row should have index as 17. My mistake. Updated the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

1. `Sort` the dataframe if not already sorted.
2. `groupby` -  `['Election Year', 'Region']` and `filter` out those groups where the `diff` is greater than `10`.
3. Again use `groupby` to extract the `top 2` rows of each `group`.

```
k = df.sort_values(['Election Year', 'Region', 'Vote %'],
                   ascending=False)
df = (
    k.groupby(['Election Year', 'Region'])
    .filter(lambda x: any(x['Vote %']
                          .diff()
                          .abs()
                          .gt(10)
                          .iloc[:2])
            )
    .groupby(['Election Year', 'Region'])
    .apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:2])
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
  Election Year  Votes  Vote %                 Party Region
0           2000  42289   29.40   Janata Dal (United)      A
1           2000  27618   11.20  Rashtriya Janata Dal      A
2           2005   1834   28.06                   NJM      B
3           2005   1334   15.06           Nationalist      B
4           2010  21114   20.80           Independent      A
5           2010   1042   10.50   Bharatiya Janta Dal      A
```

*NOTE* : Drop the extra columns (if required).

Comment: How can I find if two largest parties in every region has Vote% less than 10?

Comment: Groupby and then filter for those where the vote % itself is less than 10